# How To Make A Post Request Using Redux Thunk With Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I have been using `Redux-Toolkit` more than the `React-Redux`. I came across situations where I had to make `GET` requests, So I recently started using `Redux-Thunk` (before this I used `useEffect` but, as it's *not a standard way* to handle `async` functions, when using redux. I learned about `middleware`).

Here is the code of my `Thunk function` nad `extraReducer` which handles the `GET` request

```
export const fetchData = createAsyncThunk("type/getData", async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios({url});
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
    }
});

export const extraReducers = {
    [fetchData.pending]: (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
    },
    [fetchData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.products = action.payload;
    },
    [fetchData.rejected]: (state) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = true;
    },
};
```

In `fetchData` function my returned `response.data` is being used in `extraReducers` as `payload` so I can set the state easily. But, now the scenario is I have make a post request and I don't know how will I send the data to my `Thunk` function.

Comment: Have you checked the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you create the action of posting data and send the `data`:

```
export const postData = createAsyncThunk(
  "type/postData",
  async (data) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("https://reqres.in/api/users", data);
      // If you want to get something back
      return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
);
```

Then in a place where you want to send that data you just dispatch this action with the `data` argument that you want to send:

```
const handlePost = () => {
  // whatever you want to send
  const data = .........
  
  dispatch(postData(data));
}
```

If you want, you can also modify your `extraReducers` for this action.